# Inserting the result of a with cte query into a Temp Table

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to store the result of this query into a temp table:

```
WITH cOldest AS
(
    SELECT 
       *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [MyKey] ORDER BY SomeColumn DESC) AS rnDOB 
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT
    C.*
 ***    Insert into #MyTempTable *** This part doesn't work  
     FROM
     cOldest C
     WHERE
     C.rnDOB = 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Assuming this is for *SQL Server* : the CTE is good for only **one** statement - so you cannot have both a `SELECT` and an `INSERT` - just use the `INSERT`:

```
WITH cOldest AS
(
    SELECT 
       *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [MyKey] ORDER BY SomeColumn DESC) AS rnDOB 
    FROM MyTable
)
INSERT INTO #MyTempTable(Col1, Col2, ....., ColN)
  SELECT Col1, Col2, ...., ColN
  FROM cOldest C
  WHERE C.rnDOB = 1
```

This requires that the `#MyTempTable` already exists. If you want to create it with the `SELECT` - use this syntax:

```
WITH cOldest AS
(
 .....
)
SELECT c.*
INTO #MyTempTable
FROM cOldest c
WHERE C.rnDOB = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! I realized in order to be able to export the Temp table, it must be a Global temp. Into ##MyTempTable  @marc_s