# Case Statement in Where clause using the IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure if this is possible, but I want to specify a select query within an IN statement based on certain criteria. Here is my SQL Query:

```
SET @DepartmentId = (SELECT TOP 1 DepartmentId FROM Organisations WHERE OrganisationId = @OrgId)

CREATE TABLE #JustificationDetails
(
    JustificationId INT,
    Code VARCHAR(5),
    AccCategory CHAR(2),
    Description VARCHAR(200),
    ActualTotals DECIMAL(18, 2),
    CurrentTotals DECIMAL(18, 2),
    FutureTotals DECIMAL(18, 2),
    IncreaseDecreaseTotals DECIMAL(18, 2),
    IncreaseDecreasePerc INT,
    Justification VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #JustificationDetails
    SELECT 
        ISNULL(J.pkiJustificationId, 0), 
        RIGHT(A.AccountNumber, 5) AS AccVote, 
        LEFT(RIGHT(A.AccountNumber, 5), 2) AS AccCategory, 
        A.Description, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        ISNULL(J.JustificationReason, '''')
    FROM 
        Accounts A 
    INNER JOIN 
        Notes_Line_Entries NLE ON A.AccountId = NLE.fkiAccountId
    INNER JOIN 
        MasterBudgets MB ON NLE.budgetId = MB.BudgetId
    INNER JOIN 
        Organisations O ON MB.OrganisationId = O.OrganisationId
    LEFT JOIN 
        Justifications J ON O.OrganisationId = J.fkiOrganisationId
    WHERE 
        fkiNotesColumnId = 3 
        AND O.OrganisationId IN (CASE
                                    WHEN @DepartmentId = 2 
                                       THEN (SELECT OrganisationId FROM Organisations
                                             WHERE ParentOrganisationId IN (SELECT OrganisationId 
                                                                                            FROM Organisations 
            WHERE ParentOrganisationId IN (SELECT OrganisationId 
                                           FROM Organisations 
                                           WHERE ParentOrganisationId = @OrgId)))
                                    WHEN @DepartmentId = 4 
                                       THEN (SELECT OrganisationId FROM Organisations
                                             WHERE ParentOrganisationId IN (SELECT OrganisationId 
            FROM Organisations 
            WHERE ParentOrganisationId IN (SELECT OrganisationId 
                                           FROM Organisations 
                                           WHERE ParentOrganisationId = @OrgId)))
                                    WHEN @DepartmentId = 3 
                                       THEN (SELECT OrganisationId 
                                             FROM Organisations 
                                             WHERE ParentOrganisationId IN (SELECT OrganisationId 
           FROM Organisations 
           WHERE OrganisationId = @OrgId))
                                    WHEN @DepartmentId = 5 
                                       THEN (SELECT OrganisationId
                                             FROM Organisations 
                                             WHERE ParentOrganisationId IN (SELECT OrganisationId 
           FROM Organisations 
           WHERE OrganisationId = @OrgId))
                                 END)
GROUP BY 
    J.pkiJustificationId, A.Category, A.Description, 
    RIGHT(A.AccountNumber, 5), J.JustificationReason
ORDER BY 
    A.Category, RIGHT(A.AccountNumber, 5)
```

I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

If I run only one of the select queries in the IN() statement, then it works, so I am only assuming this is not possible ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess I could merge the 4 queries into 2, but effectively, there are 2 different selects

Comment: can you share the data table structure of dbo.Organisations and some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CASE statement can't return a dataset, so it can't be used with an IN clause.
I think the logic of your code can be written like this:

```
WHERE fkiNotesColumnId = 3 AND (      
  (
    @DepartmentId IN (2, 4) AND 
    O.OrganisationId IN (
      SELECT OrganisationId FROM Organisations
      WHERE ParentOrganisationId IN (
        SELECT OrganisationId FROM Organisations 
        WHERE ParentOrganisationId IN (
          SELECT OrganisationId FROM Organisations 
          WHERE ParentOrganisationId = @OrgId
        )
      )
    )
  )
  OR
  (
    @DepartmentId IN (3, 5) AND 
    O.OrganisationId IN (
      SELECT OrganisationId FROM Organisations 
      WHERE ParentOrganisationId IN (
        SELECT OrganisationId FROM Organisations 
        WHERE OrganisationId = @OrgId
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I was not aware of that. This did the job thanks! However, I needed to wrapped the where clause with a bracket `(...)` after the `fkiNotesColumnId` for this query to work. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a different way of achieving what I wanted. Even though the answer that @forpas gave was initially what helped, I needed something that could more easily drill down to the lowest level in my hierarchy structure. I made use of a `WITH CTE`

Here is the link that helped me : [WITH CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825305/inserting-the-result-of-a-with-cte-query-into-a-temp-table)

So now I use the `With Cte` to populate a temp table and I just call the Id's from that `temp table`, which now replaces that whole `Where` clause that @forpas provided.

Below is my query:

```
;with tmp (OrganisationId, ParentOrganisationId, DepartmentId) as (
select OrganisationId, ParentOrganisationId, DepartmentId
from Organisations
where OrganisationId = @OrgId
union all
select Organisations.OrganisationId, Organisations.ParentOrganisationId, Organisations.DepartmentId
from tmp
inner join Organisations on tmp.OrganisationId = Organisations.ParentOrganisationId
)

select DISTINCT OrganisationId, ParentOrganisationId, DepartmentId
INTO #MyTempTable
from tmp
WHERE DepartmentId = 6
```

DepartmentId 6 is my lowest level that I require.

```
SELECT ISNULL(J.pkiJustificationId,0), 
       RIGHT(A.AccountNumber,5) as AccVote, 
       LEFT(RIGHT(A.AccountNumber,5),2) as AccCategory, 
       A.Description, 
       0,
       0,
       0,
       0,
       0,
       ISNULL(J.JustificationReason,''),
       ISNULL(J.fkiOrganisationId,@OrgId),
       ISNULL(J.fkiUserId,'')
FROM Accounts A 
        INNER JOIN Notes_Line_Entries NLE ON A.AccountId = NLE.fkiAccountId
        INNER JOIN MasterBudgets MB ON NLE.budgetId = MB.BudgetId
        INNER JOIN Organisations O ON MB.OrganisationId = O.OrganisationId
        LEFT JOIN Justifications J ON O.OrganisationId = J.fkiOrganisationId
WHERE fkiNotesColumnId = 3 AND
       O.OrganisationId IN (SELECT OrganisationId FROM #MyTempTable)
GROUP BY J.pkiJustificationId,A.Category, A.Description, RIGHT(A.AccountNumber,5), J.JustificationReason,J.fkiOrganisationId,J.fkiUserId
ORDER BY A.Category,RIGHT(A.AccountNumber,5)
```

I am not sure if this could help or lead anyone in the right direction, but I thought I would post this in any case.

Cheers!